# Can we use the LSTM model when we have only single input, not a sequnce

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a sequence of data available. I can use this dataset to train the LSTM model. Lets say I have used t, t+1,..., t+5 to train my model and predict t+6

However; after training the model. I am looking for a way to only use the initial step(t) to predict the t+6.

Is that possible to do that using the LSTM, or the only way is to feed it by all timesteps that was used in training.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set input and output layer, but it willnt work correctly because